# Pandas: pass a large number of columns to a function using a list containing the column names

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to store the names of certain columns in a list? Then use that list to pass those columns' values into a function using apply().

Suppose I was passing 10 columns to a function (df.A to df.J) and I had a list containing the names of the columns A through J.

```
df['H'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunction(x.A, x.B, x.C, x.D ... ), axis=1)
```

How could I write that using the list instead of having to type out each column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass columns names in list `cols` and then `*` for unpacking:

```
np.random.seed(26)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  5  6  0
1  1  6  3
2  0  4  2

def myfunction(a,b,c):
    return (a,b,c)

cols = ['A','B','C']
df['out'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: myfunction(*x), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C        out
0  5  6  0  (5, 6, 0)
1  1  6  3  (1, 6, 3)
2  0  4  2  (0, 4, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks that's quite cool. What is the *x term called? I want to learn more about that.

Comment: It is called `asteriks` operator.